# Django TemplateDoesNotExist error keeps showing and files are not in the `django/contrib/admin/templates/` directory

Tags: django

I created a templates directory in my django project and then created `fun` directory inside of which i have `fun.html` file.In order to access this file i have the following code in my `views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def index(request):
    template_name = 1
    return render(request,'fun/fun.html')
```

and here is the directory of my project:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SChlq.png)

I checked `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/` and unfortunately nor my directory nor my files were there.

I tried Changing template 'DIRS', in settings.py to `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),` and rerunning the server,neither worked.

My templates setting:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Comment: I don't understand why you think your files would be in the Django admin templates directory. But you need to show your full TEMPLATES setting.

Comment: @DanielRoseman i added settings code.The error page says `jango.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/fun/fun.html (Source does not exist)`,so i assumed it's supposed to be there

Comment: No, it's telling you the directories it looked in. From that you can see that it's not looking in the directory you actually put your templates in. And the reason for that is you have not added your "fun" app to the list of INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: @DanielRoseman It worked! Thank you!